# probability density histogram with Matplotlib doesnt make sense

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, probability-density

I have just run a simple task of trying to plot the probability density histogram for a simulation I ran. However, when I plot it, the probability for each bin seems not to match the result of the frequency plot. with 50 bins i would expect each bin to have an average probability of 2% which is not reflected in the chart.

Thanks in advance

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plntAcres = 88.0
hvstPer = 0.99
hvstAcres = plntAcres*hvstPer
yldAcre = np.random.triangular(47,48,49, 10000)

carryIn = 464
pdn = hvstAcres * yldAcre
imp = 25.0
ttlSup = carryIn + pdn + imp

crush = np.random.uniform(1945, 1990,10000)
expts = np.random.uniform(2085, 2200,10000)
seedRes = 130
ttlDem = crush + expts + seedRes

carryOut = ttlSup - ttlDem

print carryOut

plt.hist(carryOut, bins=50,normed=True)
plt.title("Carry Out Distribution")
plt.xlabel("Value")
plt.ylabel("Probability")
plt.show()
```

[Probability density of Carry out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYnGB.png)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the `hist` function, the `normed` argument does not result in probabilites, but in probability densities. If you want the probabilities themselves, use the `weights` argument instead (and supply with `1 / len(carryOut)`).

The crucial two lines:

```
weights = np.ones_like(carryOut) / (len(carryOut))
plt.hist(carryOut, bins=50, weights=weights)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your schema is a Bell Curve, usually means that your random variable is normally distributed. 
Check wikipedia for  [Normal Distribution / Gauss distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)

Comment: And for a reason. He is adding (subtracting) three random variables with comparable standard deviation. Unless they are correlated (not in this case), the result tends to be close to Gaussian (law of big numbers).

Comment: My main issue was that the inidvidual bin probabilities don't seem to be adding up to 1 and im not sure why @honza_p

Comment: Now I understand the question.